# PowerMockito.mockStatic gives NoSuchMethodError error

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot-test

Im using 
junit 4.12
powermock-module-junit4 - 1.6.1
powermock-api-mockito- 1.6.1

The error i'm getting is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when trying to use mockStatic method

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. We can't tell you what is wrong in your code when you don't disclose that code.

Comment: Please update with what you have or you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to run is in `PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` not is **PowerMockito**

Make sure you read [Exception Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) to understand what went wrong

Comment: Maybe but then how come his source compiles in the first place. Without source code, this is just guessing.